# How to modify appcompat theme in android to get same spinner as basic theme?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-theme, appcompatactivity

When i use following theme

> android:Theme.Light

and main class extends activity(Mainactivity extends Activity)

I get following output in which edittext and spinner are present

[image: edittext+spinner_good]

and when i use following theme

> "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

and main class extends AppcompatActivity(Mainactivity extends **AppCompat**Activity)

I get following output

[image: edittext+spinner_notgood]

when i use  **android:Theme.Light**  and in main class(**Mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity**)

Error:(You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity) comes

**How to have such edittext and spinner(as in first image)** ? while using AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: got the solution

android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"

android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `AppCompatActivity` or `Theme.AppCompat` if you want the UI components to look like the basic theme rather than the Material theme.

The entire point of `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat` is to make as many components as possible use the Material Design look and feel.  If you don't want that look and feel, you shouldn't be using either.

Perhaps you actually wanted to extend from [`ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity) or [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity)?

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, I'm quite curious why you want to use `Theme.AppCompat` here.

Comment: so as to get actionbar and menu easily

Comment: is it not possible to change look of edittext and spinner in Theme.appcompat ?